# How to use putExtra and getExtra intent in adapter?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, adapter

I wanted to pass some data to adapter to java class. My adapter send data but java class show null
check my code and help me if write something wrong !!!

here is my adapter class

```
 public class myadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myadapter.ViewHolder> {
        private List<Chat> values;
        private Context context;
        public static final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT=0;
        public static final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT=1;
        String text;
        FirebaseUser fuser;
        DatabaseReference reference,reference1;
        public myadapter(List<Chat> mchat,Context context) {
            this.values =mchat  ;
            this.context=context;
        }
    
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull myadapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Chat name = values.get(position);
    
            Resources res = holder.itemView.getContext().getResources();
            String cur=name.getMsgid();
            Chat prev=values.get(position-1);
            String pr=prev.getMsgid();
            Intent pre=new Intent(context,chatscreen.class);
            pre.putExtra("pmsgid",prev.getMsgid());//i want this data to my java class
            context.startActivity(pre);
    }

here is my chatscreen.java
public class chatscreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView rv2;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatscreen);
      Intent pre=getIntent();
            prevmsgid=pre.getStringExtra("pmsgid");
    mAdapter =new myadapter(mchat,getApplicationContext());
                    rv2.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 mAdapter =new myadapter(mchat,getApplicationContext());
                rv2.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

anyone knows how to get data ?help me!

Comment: why are you starting activity in `onBindViewHolder` directly? are you using any click to open or just launching it on bind ? bind will be called multiple times and it is not a best way unless the snippet is missing something which we need to know

Comment: I am not starting activity directly with OnBindViewHolder , I put only intent related codes. No I am not using any click

Answer (score 0):

```
String pr=prev.getMsgid();
Intent pre=new Intent(context,chatscreen.class);
pre.putExtra("pmsgid",pr);
((Activity) context).startActivity(pre);
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful